# Is it possible to specify an array type as the ExpressionType for an ExpressionTextBox in a Workflow Activity Designer? If so, how?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to write a custom activity designer for Windows Workflow that allows the user to bind an activity parameter in the design window (as opposed to using the Visual Studio properties dialog). Normally, I'd just write something like this:

```
<sapv:ExpressionTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Strings, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=In}" ExpressionType="??s:String[]??" HintText="The strings to combine." />
```

The problem in this case (as can be seen in the above) is that I don't know what the `ExpressionType` should be for an array type. Assuming a namespace specification of `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`, for a string, it would be `s:String`. Is it possible to do the same thing for a string array? And if so, how please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the designer to specify the array type, then examine the resulting XML?

Comment: It's a good idea - I confess I'm not quite sure how to use the designer to specify the array type though (it just gives me a box to type the ExpressionType in, and I don't know what to put in there...)

Answer (score 0):

The designer doesn't let you specify an array type in a known/published format either. I have been trying to figure out how to do the same for a generic List type and ended up capturing the "Loaded" event and setting the ExpressionType in the code behind.

XAML:

```
<sapv:ExpressionTextBox 
    Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.MyBindingPropertyName,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Out }" 
    OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}"
    UseLocationExpression="True"
    Loaded="ExpressionTextBox_Loaded">
```

And the Loaded event handler in code-behind:

```
private void ExpressionTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((System.Activities.Presentation.View.ExpressionTextBox)sender).ExpressionType = typeof(List<MyType>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got into this today, and i have a solution. I know it's late for the guy who asked it in the first place but maybe there are some others out there encountering such a scenario :

So, this is the designer:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="ARIASquibLibrary.Design.TestArrayActivityDesigner"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"  
xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation" Collapsible="False">
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
<Grid>
    <sapv:ExpressionTextBox  
            MaxWidth="150" 
            MinWidth="150" 
            Margin="5"
            OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}"
            Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.StringsList, Mode=TwoWay,
            Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter},
            ConverterParameter=In }"/>
</Grid>
```

Create a list of strings in the variables section like this:

[image]

Add it to the expression textbox:

[image]

And now here is the code for the library:

```
public sealed class TestArrayActivity : CodeActivity<String[]>
{
    // Define an activity input argument of type List<string>
    public InArgument<List<string>> StringsList { get; set; }


    protected override string[] Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.GetValue(this.StringsList);
        return new string[2];
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddArgument(new RuntimeArgument(
        "StringsList", typeof(List<String>), ArgumentDirection.In));
    }
}
```

Add the runtime argument and pay attention at how to access the elements:

[image]

That's about it. I hope it will help new comers.